Shared Preferences requires sdk version
I am a beginner in Flutter and don't have much knowledge of it and am trying to resolve this issue but no luck so far in figuring out solution to it.
Error:
The current Dart SDK version is 3.5.0-222.0.dev.  Because testing_shared_preferences requires SDK version >=3.22.1 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
I have upgraded Dart and Flutter sdk through chocolaty add path to environment variable but still issue is not resolved.
I am trying to add a shared preferences package and am done with adding dependencies.
when I run my program it shows the above error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
